# Как вставить хтмл-содержимое в contenteditable в позицию getSelection не показывая теги

Tags: javascript

Есть некий span-элемент с `contenteditable="true"`. В него могут вставлять какое то хтмл-содержимое с clipboard'a. Перед самой вставкой содержимое обрабатывается и только потом его нужно вставить в позицию курсора или вместо выделенного фрагмента. Т.е. имеем приблизительно следующее:

```
document.querySelector('span[contenteditable=true]').addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
    // дальше я обрабатываю content, удаляя разные ненужные атрибуты
    // ...
    // и потом вставляю
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    var node = document.createTextNode(content);
    range.insertNode(node);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```

Поскольку при вставке не нужно обертывать содержимое в дополнительные тэги, то я использую `document.createTextNode()` а не `.createElement()`. Но проблема в том что при `createTextNode` в момент вставки содержимого видно все его хтмл-теги, а их не нужно отображать.

Есть ли какое то решение данной проблемы? Кроме перезагрузки страницы конечно, это в крайнем случае, если другого решения нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл простое решение на англоязычном SO

Вместо

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
var node = document.createTextNode(content);
range.insertNode(node);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

нужно вставлять с помощью

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, content);
```

Странно что никто не подсказал...